# Remove &nbsp but keep the html

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove a space but every solution keep removing the inner hmtl of the target element. How do I remove only the &nbsp part?

update: realized it doesn't remove any html, but my span element is placed outside the the parent a tag when running the script.

```js
$('.topitem').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topitem">
  <div>
    <a href="#" title="text" class="desc">
      <span style="text-align:center;">
         <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="text"></a>text
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>&nbsp;<em></em>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the `<p>` in your html?

Comment: Is it only me, or you don't have any `p` elements in your snippet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if the correct selector is used this will work

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to add the correct selector @SureshPonnukalai

Comment: Could you please descripe your propbelm any further. Your code works in general, so you might want a different result but we don't understand your issue. @user3344734

Comment: What happens is that my span element is placed after the last closing a tag when I remove the space.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the replace. This is because you placed an `a` into an `a` tag, what is not allowed in general. Change the types and it will work.

Comment: Hmm Ok, thanks, will see if I can change that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a problem with the result, you could just set the `font-size` to zero, so there is no output of the `space` (or everything else) directly inside the `.topitem`. In this case you would only use `css`, don't need to use javascript fot this task.

```css
.topitem {
  font-size: 0px;
}

.topitem * {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topitem">
  <div>
    <a href="#" title="text" class="desc">
      <span style="text-align:center;"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="text" /></a>text</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  &nbsp;test
  <em>em content</em>
</div>
```

If you want to stay with a replace, simple do it as you did in your question. But as there is only one item in your example and no `p` tag at all, just use the `class` as selector here. If you have more then one item, just put the `each` around again, but insted of `p` use `.topitem`.

```js
$('.topitem').html($('.topitem').html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topitem">
  <div>
    <a href="#" title="text" class="desc">
      <span style="text-align:center;"><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="text" /></a>text</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  &nbsp;
  <em>em content</em>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! yes of course, I forgot to add the correct selector. The problem of removing html still persist though

Answer (score 0):

1st - your selector $('p') - isn't present in html code. 
you can replace all nbsp in dom element with selector by example:

```html
    $(".topitem").html(function (i, html) {
        return html.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
    });
```

Comment: Hi! yes of course, I forgot to add the correct selector. The problem of removing html still persist though

Comment: nbsp in your code is part of div.topitem, that is top level of example dom. do you mean remove that div.topitem and leave inner dom? 
something about  $(".topitem").replaceWith($(".topitem").find('*'))